# Why does my page that uses the table-cell css style show different div widths for the same width ratios?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have the following page that uses the table-cell css style to achieve a three column layout:

HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="container" class="table, fullwidth">
      <div id="header" class="table, fullwidth">Header</div>
      <div id="main" class="table, fullwidth">
        <div id="left" class="cell">Left</div>
        <div id="center" class="cell">Center Center Center Center Center Center Center </div>
        <div id="right" class="cell">Right</div>
      </div>
    <div id="footer" class="table, fullwidth">Footer</div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
  div.table { display: table; position: inherit; }
  div.fullwidth { width: 100%; }
  div.cell { display: table-cell; }
  div#header { background-color: #ffcccc; }
  div#footer { background-color: #ccffff; }
  div#left, div#right { width: 17%; background-color: #ccffcc; }
  div#center { width: 51%; background-color: #ffccff; }
```

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/q7g8k5dy/

I am trying to get the left and right columns to be a third of the width of the center column, and I am able to get this to work in the JSFiddle window if I set the percentage widths to be below 17% (for the left and right columns) and 51% (for the center column).

But the moment I set the left and right widths to more than 17% (and the center to more than 51%), the three columns no longer occupy the entire width of the page, and there is a gap between the right edge of the right div and the right edge of the page. The total width occupied gets less and less until I set the left/right divs to 24% width and the center to 72%, whereupon I get a very uneven layout, with the left div being much wider than the right.

What is going on here? Should I just accept that this is some kind of 'magic', and the best thing to do when using percentage widths to achieve a desired layout (when using the table-cell style) is to use as low percentages as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not giving class properly. There is no `,` between 2 class names. Also, you don't need to specify width of the center dic in case you want it to be adjusted automatically.
I gave left & right divs width of 20% (i.e, 1/3 of 60%) so center will be remaining 60%.

```css
div.table { display: table; position: inherit; }
div.fullwidth { width: 100%; }
div.cell { display: table-cell; }
div#header { background-color: #ffcccc; }
div#footer { background-color: #ccffff; }
div#left, div#right { width: 20%; background-color: #ccffcc; }
div#center { background-color: #ffccff; }
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="container" class="table fullwidth">
      <div id="header" class="table fullwidth">Header</div>
      <div id="main" class="table fullwidth">
        <div id="left" class="cell">Left</div>
        <div id="center" class="cell">Center Center Center Center Center Center Center </div>
        <div id="right" class="cell">Right</div>
      </div>
    <div id="footer" class="table, fullwidth">Footer</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.